# Calculate the coord of the center of a circle knowing 2 points

Tags: center, geometry

[image: oab]

Hello, then I need to calculate the center of a circle O knowing 2 points A and B.
I made a drawing because I am not able to explain in english.

Thanks

Comment: where are the two points?  on opposite sides?  at some known distance from each other along the edge?   at unknown distances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible, You need at least 3 points to unambiguously define a circle.

Comment: Even if the AOB angle is known to be right, you can have two circles, another one with the center in O mirrored by the AB line.

Comment: No, there's only one circle (2 in fact) that can passes by the two points because the center O is also at the same distance of A and B and the lines AO and BO are perpendicular.

Comment: That's what I said in the comment. Now, how do you need to "calculate" the center O? Are the A and B points given in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: sorry I didn't saw your comment... yes each point have an x and y coordinates....

Comment: OK, things are more clear now.

Let A=(x1,y1), B=(x2,y2), P=((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2) - the middle of AB. Obviously, O (actually, O1 and O2) belongs to a line orthogonal to AB, passing through P. Since AOB is isosceles and right, PO=PA=PB. PA=(x1-(x1+x2)/2;y1-(y1+y2)/2)=((x1-x2)/2;(y1-y2)/2). To get PO, you need a vector orthogonal to PA.  To do that, you swap PA's coordinates and negate one of them (you have a choice of two negations, hence PO1 and PO2): PO1=((y1-y2)/2; (x2-x1)/2); PO2=((y2-y1)/2; (x1-x2)/2), thus O1=((x1+x2+y1-y2)/2; (y1+y2+x2-x1)/2), O2=((x1+x2+y2-y1)/2; (y1+y2+x1-x2)/2). Done.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 points. Randomly choose a third. Then calculate the circle center point.
This solution meets the criteria of the circle going through the original 2 points.